# OODBMS - RDBMS difference and which one is suitable for a factory management system

Tags: rdbms, object-oriented-database

I searched a bit for the differences between OODBMS and RDBMS. I pretty much know what they are. However, how I will decide which one is better for which applications. Can anyone kindly help me please?

What I meant for factory management is: there are production lines to manufacture bottled, frozen and other food stuff. The application manages from assigning staff onto the lines, to keep the production records in the system. Which dbms is better for such systems?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a nice article by Rick Grehan that describes cases where ODBMS are useful:
http://www.odbms.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/006.04-Grehan-When-to-Use-an-ODBMS-2005.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: this is an "old curmudgeon" answer, from a guy who wrote plenty of perfectly functional accounting, manufacturing and other code before OOP came into the mainstream.
With that being said...

Factory management is classic relational database stuff, it's what it was invented to do.  The code for classic relational apps tends to follow very predictable patterns, lots of loops over retrieved rows from tables, or straight pass-through stuff: passing data up to the UI or down to the database.  If your DB is well-designed, the biz logic you code will be details in those loops or pass-throughs, but those two patterns will dominate.

An OODMS on the other hand, from the point of view of this "old curmudgeon", attempts to recast the perfectly and efficiently functional RDBMS into something that will work with classes/objects, for no discernible gain over a system that has proven itself for decades to work extremely well.  Classes have little or nothing to do with the classic code patterns that sit on top of relational databases.  In fact, they tend to complicate things and can easily get in the way.  I'm not saying don't use OOP code to deal with the database, just that OOP was invented for a different kind of problem, a problem that database apps don't happen to have.

Answer (score 1):

Decision to choose OODBMS or RDBMS does not depend upon particular application like factory management/automation.
It is depends on many criteria like

1) **Programming Paradigm** - If you [programmer] choose to visualize/implement in the OO programming language then the OODBMS is suitable to store the objects as directly into the database, but Most widely the type of DBMS Relational, because it is well established commercially and have a good mathematical background.

2) **Application Specific** - For an factory automation/management, responsiveness and fast access is important. The OODBMS are swifter than the RDBMS. If you considered for web-development then a light-weight tool like MySQL will fit a lot.

3) **Trend** -  Now there is paradigm swift from Legacy/Structural to Object/Component Oriented programming. so therefore, in this trend the OODBMS is best suitable for the Enterprise Applications like factory management, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the application layer using. If it is a simple approach more towards procedural way [which can have classes too] RDBMS is more suitable. Otherwise if you are more towards a strict object oriented system OODBMS can be used.

Answer (score 0):

I usually draw the line of usefulness at the point in which they need to be integrated into enterprise systems. If your project does not necessarily need to integrate, ODBMS is usually easier or technically superior. If you can integrate via web services or "push/pull" into an enterprise system DB, then you can still use an ODBMS, but there might be political pressure against it. (newer ODBMS/RDBMS replication like dRS for db4o may be a good fit) But if you need tight integration with legacy or enterprise datastores, then you're usually forced to use the RDBMS for one reason or another.

That said, your individual production lines might benefit greatly from an ODBMS which are great at storing oft-changing complex object models and schemas while the orchestrator system could follow my previous line of thinking.

I've been using ODBMS for many years, and have been dreading the project which requires me to return to purely relational data management. Although recent improvements in ORM tooling have made relational much more pleasant to work with, the ORM+RDBMS solution still can't keep up with ODBMS systems in a few key areas (see the [previously mentioned article](http://www.odbms.org/Introduction/whenODBMS.aspx) on odbms.org).